Как через telebot отправить несколько картинок в одном сообщение так еще и с текстом и с кнопками Inline
Хочу Отравлять пользователю сообщение в формате:
В одном сообщение от 3х фото и есть текст снизу картинок, а так же есть и кнопки из Inline

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Хочу что бы мой бот при нажатии на кнопку InlineKtyboardButton отправлял фото-альбом с текстом в одном собщеннии
